# Get Filenames or Text from File Input multiple=multiple

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

I am trying to style up my input:file.  The following SO question gets me 95% of the way there.  The difference is that I am using the HTML5 multiple=multiple attribute.

[How to style "input file" with CSS3 / Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226167/how-to-style-input-file-with-css3-javascript)

### JS

```
        $('#choose-files-button').click(function () {
            $(':file').trigger('click');
        });

        $(':file').change(function () {
            $this = $(this);
            $('#files-selected').text($this.val());
        })
```

### Html

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <span id="choose-files-button" class="btn btn-info">Choose Files</span>
        <span id="files-selected"></span>
        <button class="pull-right btn btn-primary" type="submit">Upload</button>
        <div style="height:0; width:0;overflow:hidden;">
            <input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple="multiple" value="Add Images" />
        </div>
    }
```

### The Problem

The problem is that when the text of files-selected gets set it only shows one file name in Chrome.  I haven't tested other browsers yet.  It sets it to something like **C:/Fakepath/asfd.jpg**.When you just use the `<input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" />` it says something like **3 files selected**, which is the behavior I am trying to emulate.

Is there a way to get to that text, or get the number of files selected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript. get number of files and their filenames from "input multiple" element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171013/javascript-get-number-of-files-and-their-filenames-from-input-multiple-elemen)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `this.files.length` where `this` is the `file` DOM element.

```
$(':file').change(function () {
    $('#files-selected').text(this.files.length + " file selected");
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/yQFXq/)**

Answer (score 4):

in vanilla js:

```
var fileElement = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
var files = fileElement.files;
```

or assuming you have the input element wrapped in a jQuery selector...

```
var file = $("input[type=file]");
var files = file[0].files;
```

files should be an array of files. From this you can get the number of files and the names of them. Works in latest Chrome (116) and Firefox (117)

Comment: Works in Firefox as well so I assume it's crossbrowser compatible, couldn't find any info on it by googling. BTW this works equally well in vanilla js. jqueryVariable[0] gives a standard js element. So the `.files` has nothing to do with jQuery but is built in to the browsers

Answer (score 2):

it works for me:

```
var f_img = $('#f_img')[0].files[0];
```

var n_img = f_img.name;

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Alonso/7vstg60t/10/)