# html 'input = multiple' count number of selected files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple file input like this:

```
<input multiple="multiple" type="file" name="file">
```

When I click it, I get the option to select some files. 
When I select some files click on "open", I need to display the number of files I selected (let's say in an alert box). I suppose there should be a javascript event to handle this situation, but I can't find it. How could I accomplish this?

I have tried searching around stackoverflow but haven't found a solution, although this question doesn't seem overly specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5: How to count the length of the files from the multiple-input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139244/html5-how-to-count-the-length-of-the-files-from-the-multiple-input-field)

Comment: [**How to count selected file**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232633/how-to-count-selected-files)   [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nze2B/104/)

Comment: @MrUpsidown: thank you, I haven't stumbled across that question and I searched a great deal for this issue.. I'll pay more attention next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:-

```
$("input[type='file']").on("change", function(){  
  var numFiles = $(this).get(0).files.length
   alert(numFiles);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asdasdasdas/xvLAc/84/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[type='file']").eq(0).files.length;
```