# How to get a list of files selected by an a file upload input

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, upload

I have a  element (that allows multiple file uploads). I would like to use javascript/jquery to get a list of the files that have been selected for upload. Is this possible?

The element looks like

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
```

I am receiving the files with a Play Framework (Java) controller - however that's not really useful for the question.

Comment: What kind of element is it ? and how are you adding those file upload inputs please share some code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the list from the input element's "files" property. I think this link can help you. [Javascript get number of files and their filenames from file input element with multiple attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171013/javascript-get-number-of-files-and-their-filenames-from-input-multiple-elemen)

Example:

```
$files = $('#fileInput').files;
for (var i=0, l=files.length; i<l; i++) {
     console.log(files[i].name);
}
```