# File Validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

We are working on a Email Encrypted Service. Here I have designed a html page (User Registration) where I have provided an area for uploading a file with extentions **.crt, .cer** and **.der**

This is HTML Content:

```
<section>
    <label class="label">PubLic Key File</label>
<div> 
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
</div>
    <div id="fileDisplayArea"></div>
</section>
<button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
```

Javascript Code is:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');


    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var imageType = /image.*/

        if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "";

                var img = new Image();
                img.src = reader.result;

                fileDisplayArea.appendChild(img);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
        } else {
            fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "File not supported!";
        }
    });

}
```

I have copied this **Javascript Code** (beginner in javascript) . It Only Accepts image file. I want to change this code which only accepts **.crt, .cer** and **.der** Extentions.

Thank you :)

Comment: See: How to get a list of files selected by an a file upload input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007528/how-to-get-a-list-of-files-selected-by-an-a-file-upload-input

Comment: is that not what you need?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651700/how-to-have-jquery-restrict-file-types-on-upload

Comment: @Diodeus
The link u posted:

Its Like files[i].name is the name of the file which is iterated by loop. this i understood.

Comment: You parse the filenames to look at the type.

Comment: @user1511384

yes. I need this only!

Comment: @Diodeus: yes Sure! Let Me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current regex will actually match any filename that contains the word "image" (any part of the filename that is "image" followed by zero or more characters)

If you want to match filenames that end in ".crt", ".cer" or ".der", you can use this regex:

```
var imageType = /\.crt|cer|der$/
```

You can test regular expressions using [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)