# Laravel, how do I change the button language?

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to change the language/word of the highlighted as shoen in the picture below

[Reference picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU7Mi.png)

**CODES**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<form style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 10px;" action="{{ URL::to('importExcel/1') }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Please upload file</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="file" name="import_file"/> <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Import File</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the button text of <input type="file" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file)

Comment: How about the "No file choosen"?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is part of the form control protected by the browser. After masking the input using once of the suggestions from the linked question above, you could use JavaScript to set the content of an adjacent element. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171013/javascript-get-number-of-files-and-their-filenames-from-file-input-element-with) if you need to access the filename.

Comment: same question for
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001586/change-the-no-file-chosen maybe can help you