# How do I get the number of files from HTML Input Element in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, file, input

At the moment my script can only handle one file being added:

```
fileEvent(fileInput: Event){
    this.fileName = (<HTMLInputElement>fileInput.target).files[0].name;
    this.fileSize = Math.round(((<HTMLInputElement>fileInput.target).files[0].size) / 1000);
    this.fileAdded = true;
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<input (change)="fileEvent($event)" type="file" name="files" accept=".pcap" style='display: none;' #file>
<div id="filelist" *ngIf="fileAdded">
    <p id="file">{{ fileName }}</p>
    <p id="filesize">{{ fileSize }} KB</p>
</div>
```

I'm wondering how I can get the number of files inside the Input Element. I'm trying to loop through the elements to get their names and sizes so I can display them on my website.

EDIT: Apparently I haven't tried the most obvious thing, which is adding .length at the end. That solves it.

```
this.numOfFiles = (<HTMLInputElement>fileInput.target).files.length;
```

Comment: can you add a bit more code with explanation what you want?

Comment: @PardeepJain I hope that's enough

Comment: @DariusNein You are only taking one file at a time in your input. Then how can you get multiple?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript get number of files and their filenames from file input element with multiple attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171013/javascript-get-number-of-files-and-their-filenames-from-file-input-element-with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call your **fileInput.target.files.length**. It's already an array of files.

```
fileEvent(fileInput: Event){
    this.fileName = (<HTMLInputElement>fileInput.target).files[0].name;
    this.fileSize = Math.round(((<HTMLInputElement>fileInput.target).files[0].size) / 1000);
    this.fileAdded = true;
}
```

You just need this line.

```
const numberOfFiles = fileInput.target.files.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `multiple` attribute for input type `file` like this -

```
<input multiple (change)="fileEvent($event)" type="file" name="files" accept=".pcap" #file>
```

It will return you a array of files, you will get that using -

```
fileInput.target.files
```

For more in detail please [refer](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp)

Comment: Yeah that I know, I just wasn't sure how to get the number of files in Angular. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @DariusNein what do you mean by `...get the number of files in Angular` here ?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your input so that it can take multiple files at a time using the **multiple** attribute.

```
<input (change)="fileEvent($event)" type="file" name="files" accept=".pcap" style='display: none;' #file multiple>
```

In your script, just get the length of the files.

```
fileEvent(fileInput: Event){
    console.log(fileInput.target.files.length)
}
```